# Using a Third Party Keyframes Definition

Tags: css, webkit-animation

Font Awesome includes a spin animation for elements with the class `fa-spin`. Inspection of the CSS shows that a spinning elementis implemented using a keyframes definition again called `fa-spin`.

Rather than define a new animation, I want to use this existing one in a hover selector.

```
i.fa-gear:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 2s infinite linear;
}
```

But it simply doesn't work.

Here's an example in a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fetumocoge/1/edit).

At first I thought it was because JSBin imported the CSS section before the Font Awesome rules were defined, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Curiously, is this happening because the CSS isn't live? Not sure if it's pulling the styling through on the bin, probably be the same for local. I know that if you take the CSS stylesheet code across directly the 'fa-spin' class will work and spin then. 

Apologies for my deleted answer, I jumped the gun a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but you are using the class, that is defined as

```
.fa-spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    animation: spin 2s infinite linear
}
```

so the keyframes name is **spin** and noy fa-spin